# jquery post without ajax or form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit

Is there a way in jquery to submit a post without a form. 
like can I use the function `$.post("script.php",{var1:"abc", var2: "cde"})` such that it will not run on the background but instead post and redirect the page to script.php file as if var1 and var2 were submitted via a form.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute ajax request and make redirect to url when the response comes.

```
$.post("script.php",{var1:"abc", var2: "cde"},
    function(data) {
        if (data.success) {
            window.location.href = data.redirectTo;
        }

    }
)
```

in this case response from script.php should looks like {success:true, redirectTo: "newUrl.php"}

Comment: This code did not work. U dont think i used it right. 

function (data) {
                 window.location.href = data.redirectTo: "script.php";
             }
is this fine?

Comment: i want to do something like
 ` function (data) { 
$("body").html(data); 
} `

But I need the url to be changed as well

Comment: @NevilleNazerane If you whant to execute request and cahnge body content without reloading, see this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page.

Comment: @NevilleNazerane "This code did not work" - what error you are getting?

Comment: @NevilleNazerane window.location.href = data.redirectTo: "script.php",  data.redirectTo should contain url to new url, in case of you need redirect to scipt.php, you can make - window.location.hred = "/script.php"

Comment: it shows "toReport is not defined" with `window.location.href = data.redirectTo: "script.php";`

Comment: @NevilleNazerane try this: `window.location.href = "/script.php";`